# Converting user input to lowercase - text adventure game - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologise for another simple question but I truly am stuck...I'm trying to add a .lower() method to convert any user input whether it be upper case, lower case or combo, into lower case.

I just can't figure out exactly where to add the .lower()?

This is the main function of the game:

```
def main():

for turn in range(20, 0, -1):
    print("")
    describe()
    cmd = input("Enter your command " + str(turn) + "> ")
    if cmd == "quit":
        print("You gave in so easily :-(")
        break
    elif cmd.startswith("go "):
        where = cmd[3:]
        move_cmd(where)
        if state == "dead":
            print("you are dead")
        elif state == "outside":
            print("You jimmy the door open with the crowbar and escape to your freedom!")
            break
    elif cmd.startswith("take "):
        obj_name = cmd[5:]
        take_cmd(obj_name)
    else:
        print("I do not understand '" + cmd + "'.  Try go/take/quit")
print("Game over")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I think this is the line of code to add it too...but it doesn't work...

```
cmd = input("Enter your command " + str(turn) + "> ").lower()
```

this doesn't work...do I need to add another loop or change the line of code somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The line you added should have worked. Are you sure it doesn't? try printing `cmd` immediately after

Comment: https://repl.it/H5kC/1 - it works fine. This is why the guides for how to ask a question on stackoverflow include saying what behaviour you expect it to do, and what behaviour it actually does - including any errors. When you say it "doesn't work", are you getting syntax errors, or uppercase text coming back, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string is an instance of the str class. So you can use .lower(), .upper(), etc on any string. The type returned by input() is a str. So you want this, right above your if statements that begin by checking if the command is quit:
    cmd = cmd.lower()

You might want to check out python's [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) or [standard library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) so you can look at examples and see what the standard library and types (like str!) have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the input lowercase.
You need to set the var "cmd" lowercase

```
cmd = input("Enter your command " + str(turn) + "> ")
cmd.lower()
...
if ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Instead of using **"cmd = input("Enter your command " + str(turn) + "> ")"**, use below one:

```
cmd = raw_input("Enter your command " + str(turn) + "> ")
cmd = cmd.lower()
```

**Explanation** of using **raw_input() instead of input()**:

1) input() is equivalent to eval(raw_input()), so it parses and evaluates your input as a valid Python expression.

2) eval() interprets a string as code. And if you write any command which it fails to parse, it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input("enter the number of lines"));
line=[]
print "Enter the line sequence:";
for i in range(n):
    line.append(raw_input());
for j in range(n):
    print line[j].upper();
```

`This is a way to accept the string sequence and convert them into uppercase , i hope this can solve your problem in simple way`